# Trying to pip install pygame "error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame

I'm a rookie. Not sure what I have done in the installation of brew/pip/python but I keep getting this error when I try and pip install pygame:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/<user>/tmp/.venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/g1/3v27bfbx7092tndxwyq0vdv80000gn/T/pip-install-aylw0nbn/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/g1/3v27bfbx7092tndxwyq0vdv80000gn/T/pip-install-aylw0nbn/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/g1/3v27bfbx7092tndxwyq0vdv80000gn/T/pip-record-2mhljjki/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/<user>/tmp/.venv/include/site/python3.8/pygame
         cwd: /private/var/folders/g1/3v27bfbx7092tndxwyq0vdv80000gn/T/pip-install-aylw0nbn/pygame/
    Complete output (219 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/font.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    copying src_py/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/touch_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/touch_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/overlay_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/constants_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/version_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/textinput.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/video.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    running build_ext
    building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/src_c
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/src_c/SDL_gfx
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/<user>/tmp/.venv/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/src_c/gfxdraw.o
    In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:
    In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:
    src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
    #include <SDL.h>
             ^~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/<user>/tmp/.venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/g1/3v27bfbx7092tndxwyq0vdv80000gn/T/pip-install-aylw0nbn/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/g1/3v27bfbx7092tndxwyq0vdv80000gn/T/pip-install-aylw0nbn/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/g1/3v27bfbx7092tndxwyq0vdv80000gn/T/pip-record-2mhljjki/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/<user>/tmp/.venv/include/site/python3.8/pygame Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Tried ```py -m pip install pygame```? sometimes it fixes installation issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+%27SDL.h%27+file+not+found

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear, you need to install SDL first with brew (pip will not install any brew package, it will only install Python modules, which SDL isn't).